# Getting RSSI value using raspberry pi and python

Tags: raspbian, python, wifi

I don't know I should ask this question here or not !! I am working on indoor localization using BLE and wifi.I'm using python programming to get the RSSI value. I'm using a raspberry pi as an anchor node.

Now let's say I have some wifi access points and I want to know the received signal strength (RSSI) of those three access points using python. Is there any python library for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For Python related things you might have more luck at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: You running Python on windows-iot?

Comment: @ppumkin I'm running python on raspbian os.

Comment: Why you put a `windows-iot` tag on then? :D

Comment: @ppumkin sorry that was mistake, edited now